# How can I close a window without bringing other windows for that app to the front?

Tags: applications, window-manager

If have multiple windows open for an app and I close one of those windows the top-most window from that app immediately jumps to the front even if it was behind a window from another app. I'm a long time Mac user and somehow I'm only just now noticing this behavior. Is there some shortcut or tool that can override this either?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of a small family of actions you can perform by adding the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  key.

If you  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  click the red dot, it won't bring the rest of the app to the front.

You can also use this for various types of window move or resize. This works either inside the same app, or for any other app window you can see at the time.